# Django Email Domain Validation with cleaned_email function works very slow after submitting

Tags: python, django, backend, crm, email-validation

Hi i am trying to write email domain validation for sign up form in django syntax with following function code. I am using the function inside class meta:

VALID_DOMAINS is a list = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com']
I am using Edge browser for test

```
    def clean_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        original_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        domain = self.cleaned_data["email"].split("@")[-1]
        if domain not in VALID_DOMAINS:
            raise ValidationError("E-mail addresses from %(domain)s are not allowed.", code="invalid", params={"domain": domain})
        
    return original_email
```

Problems are:

1. After typing this function, sign up page works very slow when trying to check with any wrong domain (any outside of VALID_DOMAINS). (after submitting the form)
2. After submitting sign up form with the wrong email domain, sign up from is not returning its original shape which is before submitting. There are also happening small corruptions, and password fields act as if passwords are not typed.

I was not expecting to work very slow after submitting form.

Comment: How many `VALID_DOMAINS` did you define?

Comment: Only 2 valid domain listed - VALID_DOMAINS is a list as ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com']

Comment: why using super?? try remove it .

Comment: Thanks for answer but nothing changes with speed, 45 seconds and more waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

You call the `__init__` function of the form, which does not make much sense:

```
def clean_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    original_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    domain = self.cleaned_data["email"].split('@')[-1]
    if domain not in VALID_DOMAINS:
        raise ValidationError(
            'E-mail addresses from %(domain)s are not allowed.',
            code='invalid',
            params={'domain': domain},
        )

    return original_email
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, actually i tried many time when not typing __init__ from SignUpForm but nothing changes with speed. Still response very slow, 45 seconds waiting to response.

Comment: @Furkan: can you show the view, template and entire form? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76217240/67579) the question.